# Exclude top and bottom n rows in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, pdo

I'm trying to query a database but excluding the first and last rows from the table. Here's a sample table:

```
id | val
--------
 1    1
 2    9
 3    3
 4    1
 5    2
 6    6
 7    4
```

In the above example, I'd first like to order it by `val` and then exclude the first and last rows for the query.

```
id | val
--------
 4    1
 5    2
 3    3
 7    4
 6    6
```

This is the resulting set I would like. Note row 1 and 2 were excluded as they had the lowest and highest `val` respectively.

I've considered LIMIT, TOP, and a couple of other things but can't get my desired result. If there's a method to do it (even better with first/last % rather than first/last n), I can't figure it out.

Comment: What RDMS are you using? SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL, etc?

Comment: There were two rows with value 1, but you removed only one out of them. So, tat should be based upon id sort?

Comment: @Robbert MySQL and PDO.

Comment: How are you defining the "first" and "last" rows of the table? Ordered by `id`?

Comment: After sorting by `val`, the first and last rows would be row 0 and row COUNT(*).

Comment: What do you mean by `row 0 and row COUNT(*)`? First and last row when sorted by `val`? In your example, two rows have the min `val` (which is `1`), it's the rows `id=1` and `id=4`. Your expected output shows that of the two only `id=1` was removed. Why not `id=4`? And must it really be one row and not both? I'm asking this because the answer you've accepted would remove both `val=1` rows from your example data. What was the actual requirement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this mate:

```
SELECT * FROM numbers
WHERE id NOT IN (
    SELECT id FROM numbers
    WHERE val IN (
        SELECT MAX(val) FROM numbers
    ) OR val IN (
        SELECT MIN(val) FROM numbers
    )
);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
Select * 
from table
where 
val!=(select val from table order by val asc LIMIT 1) 
and 
val!=(select val from table order by val desc LIMIT 1)
order by val asc;
```

You can also use UNION and avoid the 2 val!=(query)

Answer (score 1):

```
;WITH cte (id, val, rnum, qty) AS (
    SELECT  id
    ,       val
    ,       ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY val, id)
    ,       COUNT(*) OVER ()
    FROM    t
)
SELECT  id
,       val
FROM    cte
WHERE   rnum BETWEEN 2 AND qty - 1
```

Comment: That won't work with MySQL which doesn't have window functions.

Comment: This is now supported with all main DBMS, and it's far more efficient than the other answers proposed, as it's the only one running in linear time, running subqueries takes `O(n^2)`

Answer (score 0):

What if you use `UNION` and exclude the `val` you don't want. Something like below

```
select * from your_table
where val not in (
select top 1 val from your_table order by val

union

select top 1 val from your_table order by val desc)
```